# displaying messages in div when jquery filter returns no result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement an if/else statement to a Jquery Code snippet I have.

Since I'm very inexperienced javascript/Jquery user I'm having problems finding out were I should add the if/else.

As the snippet is now, it shows a div if there is a match and if there is no match it shows nothing. I want it to show messages when it find no match.

```
  $("#studyselector").change(function(){
var selectItem = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
filter(selectItem);
});

function filter(e) {

  var regex = new RegExp('\\b\\w*' + e + '\\w*\\b');
        $('.listItem').hide().filter(function () {
      return regex.test($(this).data('name').toLowerCase())
  }).show();
}
```

here is a link to a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dadihall/jL0px5dw/4/)

```js
$("#studyselector").change(function(){
  var selectItem = $(this).val();
  filter(selectItem);
});
function filter(e) {
    var regex = new RegExp('\\b\\w*' + e + '\\w*\\b');
        $('.listItem').hide().filter(function () {
        return regex.test($(this).data('name'))
    }).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="studyselector">
    <option value="everything">everything</option>
     <option value="science">science</option>
     <option value="nature">nature</option>
     <option value="arts">arts</option>
  </select>

<div id="listSelection">

<div class="listItem" data-name="science, nature" >
  <h3>Science Collection</h3>
  <span class="fieldstudy">science, stars, something</span>
  <p>Science and stuff </p>
  <p>Databases: Science Global, Science Dateline, Science Trade and Industry, Science Archive</p>
</div>

<div class="listItem" data-name="nature"  >
  <h3>Academic Search DB</h3>
  <span class="fieldstudy">everything</span>
  <p>All Studies </p>
    <p>  1000 references  </p>
    <p>  Texts from 4500 magazines and 1000 peer previewed articles</p>
</div>

<div class="listItem" data-name="arts" >
  <h3>Nature Science</h3>
  <span class="fieldstudy">nature, science</span>
  <p>All Studies </p>
    <p>  Nature and more  </p>
    <p>  6000 natur articles and 1000 peer previewed articles</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Which select option is supposed to not show anything?

Comment: `everything` ;)

Comment: Oxymoronish enough :D

Comment: Actually, I assumed there was something missing in the everything selection which only works the first time. See my answer for a more useful solution

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, It really helped. I decided to go with @ipraxa Inc answer since it was in away the simplest and basically exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Slowboy What do you mean, the simplest? My answer addressed two more issues in your code and showing a message when nothing found was just one of them which I solved without needing to hide the message. The extra code I had was `if (selectItem == "everything") $('.listItem').show(); else` plus  
`$("#message").toggle($('.listItem:visible').length === 0);` plus `.change();`
How was that complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Try This:-

Add Html:-

```
<div class="error" style="display: none;">Not Found</div>
```

Js:-

```
$("#studyselector").change(function(){
    var selectItem = $(this).val();
    filter(selectItem);
  });
  function filter(e) {
      var regex = new RegExp('\\b\\w*' + e + '\\w*\\b');
            $('.listItem').hide().filter(function () {
          return regex.test($(this).data('name'))          
      }).show();

      if($('.listItem:visible').length===0){
        $('.error').show();
      }else{
        $('.error').hide();
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add this :

```js
// bottom filter function

if($("#listSelection").children(":visible").length == 0) {
  $(".empty").show();
} else {
  $(".empty").hide();
}
```

`.empty` just class for html element that hold empty message, here a jsfiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/anaselalami/jL0px5dw/56/), based on your code

Answer (score 1):

You need to show a message but also show all when everything is selected

Here I toggle a message if the filter resulted in nothing visible.

I ALSO initialise to show whatever is selected when the page loads AND allow the everything to show everything after another selection is made

```js
$("#studyselector").change(function() {
  var selectItem = $(this).val();
  if (selectItem == "everything") $('.listItem').show();
  else filter(selectItem);
  $("#message").toggle($('.listItem:visible').length === 0);
}).change();

function filter(e) {
  var regex = new RegExp('\\b\\w*' + e + '\\w*\\b');
  $('.listItem').hide().filter(function() {
    return regex.test($(this).data('name'))
  }).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="studyselector">
  <option value="everything">everything</option>
  <option value="science">science</option>
  <option value="nature">nature</option>
  <option value="arts">arts</option>
  <option value="nothing">nothing</option>
</select>

<div id="listSelection">

  <div class="listItem" data-name="science, nature">
    <h3>Science Collection</h3>
    <span class="fieldstudy">science, stars, something</span>
    <p>Science and stuff </p>
    <p>Databases: Science Global, Science Dateline, Science Trade and Industry, Science Archive</p>
  </div>

  <div class="listItem" data-name="nature">
    <h3>Academic Search DB</h3>
    <span class="fieldstudy">everything</span>
    <p>All Studies </p>
    <p> 1000 references </p>
    <p> Texts from 4500 magazines and 1000 peer previewed articles</p>
  </div>

  <div class="listItem" data-name="arts">
    <h3>Nature Science</h3>
    <span class="fieldstudy">nature, science</span>
    <p>All Studies </p>
    <p> Nature and more </p>
    <p> 6000 natur articles and 1000 peer previewed articles</p>
  </div>
  <div id="message">Nothing found</div>
</div>
```